# Representing bytes in QShell AS/400 (iSeries)

Tags: ibm-midrange, qshell

I am having problems using unix tools that I usually use because I cannot use some characters in QSHell. For example, in linux, I can replace specific bytes on a file like this:

sed 's/l/\x81/' a.txt

In that case, I am replacing 'l' by the byte x81. However, in Qshell, I cannot use \x , for example,

```
printf '\x81'
Öx81
```

As we see, \x81 does not print as an 'a', which is the \x81 in EBCDIC, the encoding from iSeries. It doesn't even try to print a byte, it is printing a string of length 4...

What I am trying to do is simply using sed to replace the carriage return, by carriage return and new line and things like that. I realized that the character \ is not present in EBCDIC, as neither are {}. So, there are also some unix commands that use those characters that show an error in QShell. Please help, I cannot find a way to make things work online, so I am failing to write any script.

To make the question not ambiguous, I specifically need a way to printf a character using its hex representation in Qshell.

I am using PCOMM tn5250 to connect to the AS/400.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the escape like this:

`printf \\x81`

`a`

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt work,  printf "\\x81" 
 ÖÖx81$

Did you configure something on the tn5250 or change the encoding of qshell or anything like that?  thanks

Comment: I used ssh to access the system and then started qsh.  You may need to config the code page of the terminal emulator.